# VBA Excel: Insert a new column every nth column filled with a formula which refrences the immediate column to the left

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to insert a new column every other column about 260 times, then I need to fill the new columns with a formula which references the immediate column to the left. Here is what I have to insert a new column:

```
Sub insert_column_every_other()
For colx = 2 To 266 Step 2
Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Next
End Sub
```

But I am stuck on the formula, it merely copies the formula as is.. I need the C3 value to change and reference the immediate column to the left (other parts might not be 100% I am new to VBA so all corrections are appreciated):

```
Sub Repeat()
For ColNum = 3 To 2000 Step 2
    Range(Cells(2, ColNum), Cells(21, ColNum)).FormulaR1C1 ="=AVERAGE(OFFSET(C3,1,0,2,1))"
Next ColNum
End Sub
```

Comment: In the formula change `C3` to `C[-1]`.  That said, your formula looks suspect.  What do you want it to do?

Comment: In R1C1 notation, `C3` means the same as what `$C:$C` means in A1 notation.  @chrisneilsen's suggestion will generate the equivalent of `B:B` when the formula is in column C, `D:D` when the formula is in column E, etc.  (But as Chris says, that seems suspect when coupled with a row-extending `OFFSET`.)  But if you are intending `C3` to mean the cell one column to the left and one row below the cell where the formula is placed, you may as well just use a R1C1 formula of `=AVERAGE(R[2]C[-1]:R[3]C[-1])` and avoid the `OFFSET` entirely.

Comment: @chrisneilsen...I have a data set with two measurements per sample(in ~100 rows) for ~267 types of measurements(columns). I need to extract an average of each type of measurement for the two reps and eventually I need to cut the # of rows in half to only display the average values.

Comment: @YowE3K...I like simplifying things, and I did avoid the OFFSET, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the next code should do what you want

```
Sub insert_column_and_Formula()
   Dim colx As Long
   Dim H As Worksheet
   Set H = H3 'Replace H3 with the sheet that contains your data

   For colx = 2 To 266 Step 2
      'Insert the Column' 
      Call H.Columns(colx).Insert(Shift:=xlToRight)
      'Put the formula in the new Column'
      H.Range(H.Cells(2, colx), H.Cells(21, colx)).FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(OFFSET(RC[-1],1,0,2,1))"

   Next colx
End Sub
```

Hope this help you, any question let me know please

Comment: You're missing an `H.` object reference to qualify one of the `Cells`.

Comment: @FernandoCT... Here is the polished code from your suggestions...Thanks...        `Sub insert_column_and_Formula()
   Dim colx As Long
   Dim H As Worksheet
   Set H = Sheet1 'Sheet1= Sheet name that contains the data'
   For colx = 4 To 536 Step 2
      'Insert the Column'
      Call H.Columns(colx).Insert(Shift:=xlToRight)
      'Put the formula in the new Column'
      H.Range(H.Cells(2, colx), H.Cells(41, colx)).FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[0]C[-1]:R[1]C[-1])"
      'which is the same as..."=AVERAGE(OFFSET(RC[-1],0,0,2,1))"'
   Next colx
End Sub`