# VBA-excel inserting a new cell every nth row in a dataset

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very basic knowledge of VBA coding and am in dire need of some help.

I want to insert an empty cell every nth row in my data set.

I have found the following VBA which achieves a similar goal and i was wondering if anyone has an idea of tweaking the linked or have had a similar problem.

[VBA Excel: Insert a new column every nth column filled with a formula which refrences the immediate column to the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41865318/vba-excel-insert-a-new-column-every-nth-column-filled-with-a-formula-which-refr?s=1|121.0419)

Comment: Instead of `Columns(colx).Insert(Shift:=xlToRight)` you should insert a Row `Rows(i).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown` or `Rows(i).Insert shift:=xlShiftUp`

Answer (score 1):

Use union method.

```
Sub insertRow()
    Dim rngU As Range, rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 4 To 20 Step 3
        If rngU Is Nothing Then
            Set rngU = Range("a" & i)
        Else
            Set rngU = Union(rngU, Range("a" & i))
        End If
    Next i
    rngU.EntireRow.Insert
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
 Do you know if there is a way to insert rows alternating between to numbers, such as n and n+1?